# Beginner Python: Checking Membership In Dictionary and Using Decision Structures

Tags: python, typeerror

I was working on code and ran across an issue where I'm trying to use an if-statement based on if user input is found in a dictionary. For example lets say if a user wants to find a name in an address book and I save their response to a variable "findName" which is the key for the dictionary. Let's also say the dictionary name is "contact".

```
if contact.has_key[findName] == True: 
    #Do something here. 
elif contact.has_key[findName] == False: 
    #Do something else.
```

The problem is that every time I do this, I get an error message saying: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.

I don't really know where my code went wrong, can someone guide me to the correct answer and explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling the has_key method.

It should be

```
if contact.has_key(findName) == True: 
    #Do something here. 
elif contact.has_key(findName) == False: 
    #Do something else.
```

A more pythonic way to do this is to use `in` and you don't need to check for the False condition you can use use `else`.

```
if findName in contact: 
    #Do something here. 
else: 
    #Do something else.
```

Comment: @Jr.: It's an easy mistake to make when you are just starting out

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error. There shouldn't be a colon after `elif`, and has_key is a method:

```
if contact.has_key(findName) == True: 
    #Do something here. 
elif contact.has_key(findName) == False: 
    #Do something else.
```

But this, of course, can just be reduced to:

```
if contact.has_key(findName): 
    #Do something here. 
else:
    #Do something else.
```

Comment: @GWW I'm afraid not: 
`File "<stdin>", line 3
    elif: pass
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: My apologies, I think the question must have been edited because the colon isn't there anymore.